# How to convert a string value to type "System.Int32" in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, datetime, timespan

I was trying to get the count of days between two dates, but getting the below error

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

```
$Days = $expiration - $currentDate
Cannot convert value "12/28/2020" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At line:1 char:1
+ $Days = $expiration - $currentDate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastFromStringToInteger
```

below is a snippet of code for reference

```
$expiration = $QueryResults.Results.ExpiryDate_s
$expiration
12/28/2020

$currentDate = Get-Date -Format 'MM/dd/yyyy'
$currentDate
09/30/2020


$expiration.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                              
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                              
True     True     String                                   System.Object

$currentDate.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                              
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                              
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to cast them to INTs, rather than DateTime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PowerShell directly supports subtracting [`[datetime]` (`System.DateTime`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime) instances**, the **result** of which is reported as a **span of time**, expressed as a [`[timespan]` (`System.TimeSpan`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.TimeSpan) instance.

For this to work, ***both* operands passed to the `-` (subtraction) operator must be of type `[datetime]`**, which in your case you can simply be achieved by *casting*<sup>[1]</sup> your string operands to that type (instead of calling `Get-Date -Format 'MM/dd/yyyy'` you should just call `(Get-Date).Date` in order to return a `[datetime]` instance directly):

```
PS> [datetime] '12/28/2020' - [datetime] '09/30/2020'

Days              : 89
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 0
Ticks             : 76896000000000
TotalDays         : 89
TotalHours        : 2136
TotalMinutes      : 128160
TotalSeconds      : 7689600
TotalMilliseconds : 7689600000
```

To get just the count of days between the two dates, using the current date (without a time-of-day component) as the RHS:

```
$days = ([datetime] '12/28/2020' - (Get-Date).Date).Days
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

**If you pass a *string*-typed LHS to the `-` operator, PowerShell tries to interpret it *as a number***.

Since a string such as `'12/28/2020'` cannot be parsed as a numeric type, the operation fails. To provide a more obvious example:

```
PS> 'I am not a number' - 1
Cannot convert value "I am not a number" to type "System.Int32"
...
```

`[int]` (`System.Int32`) just happens to be the one numeric type chosen for the error message.

---

<sup>[1] Note that PowerShell casts are always based on the *invariant culture*, which is based on the US English culture, irrespective of what culture is currently in effect. This means that a `[datetime]` cast accepts whatever string `[datetime]::Parse($string, $null)` accepts, which includes month-first date strings such as `'1/13/2020'` as well as less ambiguous formats such as `'2020-1-13'`</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do math against datetime data type values which is not correct.

I belive you could use `New-TimeSpan` cmdlet to achieve your needs. Like so:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> New-TimeSpan -Start '01.01.2020' -End $(Get-Date)


Days              : 274
Hours             : 3
Minutes           : 38
Seconds           : 17
Milliseconds      : 295
Ticks             : 236866972950824
TotalDays         : 274,151589063454
TotalHours        : 6579,63813752289
TotalMinutes      : 394778,288251373
TotalSeconds      : 23686697,2950824
TotalMilliseconds : 23686697295,0824
```

You could also invoke datetime data type variable's methods such as `AddDays()`. Like so:

```
  PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $CurrentDate = Get-Date
  PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $CurrentDate.AddDays(-274)
    
    1 января 2020 г. 3:40:59
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. It is clear now and the script is working fine with `New-TimeSpan -Start -End`

Comment: While your solution works, your claim that an attempt to do "math against datetime data type values which is not correct" is false: using subtraction (`-`) between two `[datetime]` instances works just fine and directly returns a `[timespan]` instance. @VINODKUMAR's only problem was the use of _string_ operands as-is, without casting to `[datetime]` first.